# How to replace my kitchen sink basket with no lock nut?

Tags: plumbing

I have a kitchen sink basket that's leaky and has a bunch of gunk caught under it. I want to replace it. All the instructions I see for removing and replacing a kitchen sink basket start by removing the lock nut underneath:

[image]

My sink, however, doesn't have a lock nut. The pressure cup is plastic and I have no idea how to remove it.

[image]

Here's what it looks like from the top. I tried holding that little center piece steady with a screw driver and tried to unscrew the basket from beneath, but it just turns and turns and won't loosen. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Well, first remove the plastic plumbing by unscrewing the lock nut - which is that big white flanged thing.  Then see if you can drop that plastic outer cup and tap free the basket.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Hey Carl - I had the plastic pipes detached this morning the plastic cup is definitely fixed, just not sure how. It won't come free by twisting or tapping it.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest a bigger hammer :-) . Try putting a pry bar (or paint-can lid opener) between the sink and the top of the plastic cup to see if it's snap-on.  You sure you can rotate that plastic cup?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The plastic cup spins with ease. When I turn it, the screw that attaches to the strainer also turns (unless I hold it).

Comment: Advice from May 16, 2016 was solid. I managed to get one off with a very big screwdriver wedged sideways and the second one I drilled out from above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this looks like a chinese unit one of my granite suppliers used to use.  they are the biggest piece of junk on the planet.  if i remember correctly, the small screw in the middle acts as a retainer for the whole unit.  you have unscrew it from above, and it holds the whole thing together.  the problem we had was that the screw got locked into the metal insert thats in the lower plastic section and just seizes right up.  our solution was a heat gun.  just melt the lower bowl and keep pulling it out in chunks until you can get a grinder in and cut the bolt.  then throw everything away and start again, using a quality metal strainer assembly

Comment: I was about to say this... but felt like he had kind of figured it out based on his last comment (the screw... also turns (unless I hold it)).

Comment: Yea, I have one similar to this and the screw broke and it leaked under my sink for weeks probably without me knowing.

Comment: Screw was locked and we sawed the plastic section off. Replaced with a full metal strainer.

Answer (score 2):

That screw from the top is threaded into a brass insert which is pressed into the large plastic cone. These bushings sometimes start to turn in the plastic and you cannot unscrew the drain. You’ll need to cut away the plastic portion, just underneath the steel strainer at the top. Usually there are 4 plastic arms that hold the retainer in the middle of the plastic cone. Use a cutting drill bit on your drill to get in there and cut the plastic away. Once you cut away these pieces, the drain will come out, just pull up on it. you’ll then need to go to a hardware store and get a complete drain.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.