# How to fix Kitchen drain that came apart?

Tags: drain, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

My kitchen drain came apart, it is like 12 years old. I noticed it is not a locknut connection, so I am not sure how to attach these parts. The sink strainer itself is loose and I can pull it out easily, so I was wondering if I need to reseal it as well? Above the connection you see a black washer. Any advice?

**UPDATE** - Per Ben's advice after looking closer I could see it did have a drain screw and it broke in half. Below you can see what it looks like. Now I just got to find this part and replace it every 10 years from now on.

**UPDATE 2** - I shopped around to a big box and a plumbing supply store, but it seems such retaining screw is rare and none of them ever recall stocking such a part. They also said that was a unusual way of making such an assembly. So I am just going to replace it with a Deep Cup Strainer that should fit in perfectly. If that screw went after 12 years it is bound to go again. And since this is a double sink, I am going to replace both of them.

[image]

[image: The broken drain screw]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you lost a (retaining) screw. It might have fallen down the drain... hopefully it's lodged in the p-trap. This is similar to: [How to replace my kitchen sink basket with no lock nut?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/how-to-replace-my-kitchen-sink-basket-with-no-lock-nut)

[image]

Comment: How funny, they just posted that question yesterday. Anyway if it broke once, it is bound to break again, I may replace it with a traditional one, but will look for the screw first.